# Drupal : I need a process where I can manage the url link when the language changes in a multilingual site

Tags: drupal-7

Drupal : I need a process where I can manage the url link when the language changes in a multilingual site. example " when one changes the site language from en to french "www.example.com/en/Example" should be changeable to "www.example.com/fr/Exemple(in French)"

Comment: Hi! Welcome to SO. Please provide us a bit of code and some info with what have you tried and where are you getting the errors.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. But i got the solution for this by some R&D.

Comment: If you have the solution, please answer your own question. If somebody is facing the same issue will be useful your knowledge